# Haskell Show instance

Tags: haskell

I have this data type `data SigT a p = ExistT a p` and I want to write a specified `Show` for it. I tried this:

```
instance Show (SigT Integer Integer) where
  show (ExistT q r) = "quotient = " ++ show q ++ "remainder = " ++ show r
```

But I get this error:

```
EXAMPLE_05_Driver.hs:8:10: error:
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘Show (SigT Integer Integer)’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Show (SigT Integer Integer)’
```

Comment: You can fix it by using `instance (Show a, Show p) => Show (SigT a p) where`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read this part of the error message: "Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this."? This refers to the `FlexibleInstances` language extension, which you can enable by writing

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
```

on top of a source file, or (if you are in ghci) by writing `:set -XFlexibleInstances`